# What is the side effect of using CSPRNG radix

Tags: node.js, random, cryptography

Given following code example from npm package [csprng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csprng), the rand function contain 2 parameters, they are `rand(bits, radix)`.

So, what is the side effect of using radix?

```
var rand = require('csprng');

rand(160, 36) // -> 'tq2pdxrblkbgp8vt8kbdpmzdh1w8bex'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "side effect"?

Comment: There should be no difference. Encoding, like in Base16, Base32 or Base64, is just a presentation detail. A "raw" string and the encoded string each have the same amount of entropy in them.